# nightwatch assert ALL elements, not ANY

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm trying to test that, when the Submit button is clicked on an empty form, all the "please fill in this field" labels are displayed.

I'm doing so with this:

```
page.click('@btn_submit');
page.expect.element('@validation_label_required').to.be.visible;
```

where @validation_label_required is represented by the CSS selector:

```
input[required] ~ p.error-message-required
```

However, this test passes if ANY of the validation labels are visible. The test should only pass if they ALL are.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a custom assertion for that where you locate all elements by selenium commands and then loop to verify condition. It should look something like this

```
var util = require('util');
exports.assertion = function (elementSelector, expectedValue, msg) {

    this.message = msg || util.format('Testing if elements located by "%s" are visible', elementSelector);

    this.expected = expectedValue;

    this.pass = function (value) {
        return value === this.expected;
    };

    this.value = function (result) {
        return result;
    };

    this.command = function (callback) {
        var that = this.api;
        this.api.elements('css selector',elementSelector, function (elements) {
            elements.value.forEach(function(element){
              that.elementIdDisplayed(element.ELEMENT,function(result){
                if(!result.value){
                  callback(false);
                 }
               });
             });
            callback(true);
        });
        return this;
    };

};
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, and apologies for the slow response. I'm surprised that this functionality isn't covered by the core api though - assuming you mean "any" elements is a fairly big assumption to make on its part.

Answer (score 0):

I've just ended up with another custom assertion that check how many elements are visible by given css selector.

```
/**
 * Check how many elements are visible by given css selector.
 * 
 */

var util = require('util');
exports.assertion = function(elementSelector, expectedCount, msg) {

this.message = msg || util.format('Asserting %s elements located by css selector "%s" are visible', expectedCount, elementSelector);

this.expected = expectedCount;

this.count = 0;

this.pass = function(value) {
    return value === this.expected;
};

this.value = function(result) {
    return this.count;
};

this.command = function(callback) {
    var me = this, elcount = 0; 
    this.count = 0;
    this.api.elements('css selector', elementSelector,  function(elements) {

        if(elements.value && elements.value.length > 0){
            elcount = elements.value.length;                
        }else{
            return callback(false);
        }
        elements.value.forEach(function(element) {
            me.api.elementIdDisplayed(element.ELEMENT, function(result) {
                if (result.value) {
                    me.count++;
                }
                elcount--;
                if (elcount === 0) {
                    callback(me.count);
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
};
```